# Sending sms through my application coded in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

My client requires an sms to be sent to him, whenever an invoice is made on his system by any of the employees.  I have no idea how to configure it.  Do I need to buy any sms-server service?

How to integrate into my application?

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what country you are in. But in the UK i use [this provider.](http://www.textlocal.com/)

They have [excellent examples](http://www.textlocal.com/developers/code/)

I can send SMS from my webserver, my Windows .NET Form application, a iPhone app if i wanted to. This is possible because it uses a simple HTTP Request API, so even using JavaScript AJAX from the client will work.

Just search for `SMS Gateway` and find your countries advisability. Look at a few and decide which one suits your needs and also the costs involved.

My Provider charger per sms.. no signup fees, no contracts, just top up.

---

Using a mobile phone is more involved, but obviosly it has the benefit that you control every aspect of sending, receiving and processing data.

**for example  [1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FL7J1bL_MmA), [2](http://www.wrankl.de/SMST4PIC/SMST4PIC.html), [3](http://www.serasidis.gr/circuits/smscontrol/smscontroller.htm)**

---

You can even [buy a module](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/GSM-SIEMENS-TC35-SMS-Wireless-Module-UART-232-/200524455404?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2eb0305dec#ht_4916wt_952) from china just designed to interface via Serial to send/recieve SMS, and even use the GPRS to get/send HTTP request.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for such detailed answer.  I am based in Pakistan

Answer (score 0):

There is two option

1) have to buy service from provider or

2) you have to connect your mobile with pc and send msg using AT command

Comment: Thanks for your response.  could you please advise me any web-based companies where I could buy the service.  I donot want to involve mobile........  Need to send through computer

Answer (score 0):

A lot of carriers will allow SMS via e-mail.  This may be a better option for you.

Here is a [list](http://allthingsmarked.com/2006/09/04/howto-send-free-text-messages-through-email/) of the e-mail address formats for a number of carriers.

Comment: Thanks !but my issue is probably beyond your reach.  Do you know any services that could be used internationally?  I want to use it from Pakistan to Pakistan.